# Entries From Mongo Collection Newer Than 24 Hours

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, meteor, time

I have a Mongo Collection called `Posts` which I'm using in my Meteor project in which each element has a field called `date` which holds the date at which the entry was created.

I need a query which I can execute on my collection that will return only entries which have been created in the last 24 hours.

I have the following query:
`Posts.find({date: {$gt: new Date("Mar 10, 2016")}});`

Which works to return the posts that were created on March 10th, However, I think I need to replace `Mar 10, 2016` with the date 24 hours ago in order to achieve what I want, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without installing any packages:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
Posts.find({date: {$gt: d}});
```

With [moment](https://atmospherejs.com/momentjs/moment):

```
Posts.find({date: {$gt: moment().subtract(1, 'day').toDate()}});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [momentjs](https://atmospherejs.com/momentjs/moment) package to easily do date math in js:

```
Posts.find({ date: { $gt: moment().subtract(24,'hours').toDate() }});
```